# How to convert a List of Map(string,string) to a List of strings with only a specific key

Tags: groovy

What I currently have is list of maps

```
[{"title":"Witcher","desc":"456"},{"title":"Harry Potter","desc":123},{"title":"ozark","desc":"879"}]
```

I want to end up with is a list of titles.

```
["Witcher","Harry Potter","ozark"]
```

My current code somewhat like this

```
ListMap.stream().filter({ map -> map.containsKey("Title") }).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Please provide [mre]

Comment: `def titles = listMap*.title`

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
  def map = [["title":"Witcher","desc":"456"],["title":"Harry Potter","desc":123],["title":"ozark","desc":"879"]]
  
  def names = map.collect{entry -> entry.title}
  
  println(names)
```

Comment: Or just `map*.title`